# Server side render react components bundled with webpack - PHP

Tags: php, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I have multiple entry points which I need to SSR with php. Every entry point is an own bundle. I am trying to get it working using 
[react-php-v8js](https://github.com/reactjs/react-php-v8js).
When I pass the component name in the setComponent method

```
$react->setComponent('MyComponent', ...);
```

I get the error:
"MyComponent is not defined." 
I guess that is due to the fact that webpack bundles every component in an encapsulated iife so that react-php-v8js cant access the component name.